# How to make Haskell compute the correct polymorphic type?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, types, polymorphism

I just realized how useful the little [`on`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Function.html#v%3Aon)-function can be.

Ex:

```
orderByLength = sortBy (compare `on` length)
```

But unfortunately, the inferred types can be somewhat counter-intuitive.

According to the very definition

```
f `on` g = \x y -> f (g x) (g y)
```

one could e.g. replace

```
(==) `on` length
```

with

```
\x y -> (length x) == (length y)
```

But both have different types!

The first has `[a] -> [a] -> Bool` whereas the second has the correct, more generic type of `[a] -> [b] -> Bool`.

This disallows obviously correct terms like `(on (==) length) [1, 2, 3] ["a", "b", "c"]` (which should yield `True` but now even fails type-checking).

I know this restriction comes up due to the usage of [first-rank types](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Polymorphism), but how to overcome this? Can someone formulate an implementation of `on` that can deal correctly with polymorphic functions (using universal quantification/rank-n types)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
on' :: (a -> a -> b) -> (forall d. c d -> a) -> c e -> c f -> b
on' f g x y = f (g x) (g y)
```

This results in

```
Prelude> :t on' (==)
on' (==) :: (Eq a) => (forall d. c d -> a) -> c e -> c f -> Bool
Prelude> :t on' (==) length
on' (==) length :: [e] -> [f] -> Bool
```

On the other hand, this signature also makes `flip on' id` illegal, which is somewhat less than desirable.

---

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Language.Haskell.TH
onE f g = do
    x <- newName "x"
    y <- newName "y"
    lamE [varP x, varP y] $ f `appE` (g `appE` varE x) `appE` (g `appE` varE y)
```

```
Prelude> :set -XTemplateHaskell
Prelude> $(onE [|(==)|] [|length|]) [1,2,3] ["a","b","c"]
True
Prelude> $(onE [|(==)|] [|id|]) 4 5
False
```

Comment: Cool thing - What is `c`? A kind `* -> *`? Ah, it's to wrap the potential use of `[type]` ... Can you generalize it for any *kind*?